# Button onClick inside view used in Alert Dialog

Tags: android, android-view, android-alertdialog, onclicklistener

I have a button inside a layout file that I am using to create a custom alert dialog. For unrelated reasons I need to use the buttons inside the layout as opposed to using the dialogs built-in buttons.

Its actually a very similar scenario to this question:

[Android:Button in AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895609/androidbutton-in-alertdialog)

The problem is that the onClick never seems to get called when I tap the button inside the alert dialog.

Here is the relevant portion of the code inside OnCreate in my activity:

```
LayoutInflater dcvI = LayoutInflater.from(this);
final View dcv = dcvI.inflate(R.layout.dialog,null);
final Button sd_abort = (Button)dcv.findViewById(R.id.abort1);
sd_abort.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           public void onClick(View v) {

//I do work here

}});
```

The alert dialog code:

```
View exp =  LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.dialog,null,false);

new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme)
.setTitle("Warning!!!")
.setIcon(R.drawable.dhd_icon)
.setView(exp)
.show();
```

Does anyone know if I am missing something that is keeping the button and the onclick listener from connecting?

Thanks

Comment: The two buttons don't seem connected at all.

Comment: Could you explain? The button I have in the listener "abort1" is in the layout/xml/view that I am using as a base for my alert dialog. The button shows up in the dialog. I guess my question is if I am not doing it right how can I listen for a button that is inside an alert dialog?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new button listener class

```
public class ButtonListener implements OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // do your work

    }

}
```

then set them on both of your buttons

```
ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
sd_abort.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
```

(in your dialog)

```
View exp =  LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.dialog,null,false);

Button dialogButton = (Button)exp.findViewById(R.id.abort1);
dialogButton.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme)
.setTitle("Warning!!!")
.setIcon(R.drawable.dhd_icon)
.setView(exp)
.show();
```

Comment: This seems to have worked. I don't know why it did, but it did. So thank you for all your help!